# Inline image attachment on Gmail from GDrive

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-attachments

Is there a way to attach my images directly from my Google Drive **inline** when composing a message on Gmail?

When I try to attach an inline image from a shareable link on my Google Drive, it doesn't show inline when attached, but an image is visible on the preview of image when using the `Add Photo > Web URL` functionality of Gmail.

**Getting Shareable Link from Google Drive**

[image: Getting Shareable Link from Google Drive]

**Using Insert Photo from Gmail**

[image: Using Insert Photo from Gmail]

**Photo is Not Properly Attached**

[image: Icon not inline image]

The reason why we need to use the photo from Google Drive is that we need the versioning of the file, and when we update the image, all the emails that have been sent with the image should be updated as well. We use it for our company wide announcements and resending an updated image would just spam everyone.

Is there a way for this to be possible?

Comment: Definitely not. Email isn't designed for this. imagine all the shanigans this type of functionality would allow! @

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

Use url in format

> `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=DRIVE_FILE_ID`

### Explanation

You cannot use url that Google Drive provides as "**share link**":

- *`https://drive.google.com/open?id=DRIVE_FILE_ID`*
- *`https://drive.google.com/file/d/DRIVE_FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing`*

as image src, because it's actually link to a **web page** ([MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) *`text/html`*).

Instead `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=DRIVE_FILE_ID` will return document with **needed MIME type *`image/*`*** which you can use as image source.

References:

1. [view Images that are uploaded to Google Drive - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218827/view-images-that-are-uploaded-to-google-drive/45222645)
2. [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. Email isn't designed for this, websites are though. imagine all the shanigans this type of functionality would allow.

Comment: This answer is just an opinion and not a technical fact. And a strange opinion at that... is it shaniganism sending an email with visual instructions to clients/alumns/family/friends?

Answer (score 0):

I just use https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=DRIVE_FILE_ID and that works perfectly.